# codeigniter update error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a bit confused about this error when I am updating the data. Can anyone help me with this? My codes are the following:

Controller:

```
 public function show_student($id)
{
    $data['single_student'] = $this->student_view_model->get_student_id($id);

    $this->load->view('view_student_update', $data);
}

public function student_update_info($id, $data)
{

    $data = array(
        'student_fname' => $this->input->post('first'),
        'student_lname' => $this->input->post('last'),
        'student_gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'student_course' => $this->input->post('course'),
        'student_company' => $this->input->post('company')
        );

    $data['results'] = $this->student_view_model->update_student($this->input->post('hid'), $data);

    $this->load->view('view_student_list', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_student_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_student', array('student_id' => $id));

    return $query->row_array();
}

public function update_student($id, $data)
{

    $this->db->where('student_id', $id);

    $this->db->update('tbl_student', $data);

    return $this->get_student_id($id);

}
```

**My View** ( edit page )

```
<?php echo form_open('student_update/student_update_info'); 

        $data = array(
            'id' => 'input',
            'name' => 'hid',
            'value' => $single_student['student_id']
            );
        echo form_hidden($data);

        echo form_label('First Name: ', 'first');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'input',
            'name' => 'first',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter First Name',
            'value' => $single_student['student_fname']
            );
        echo form_input($data);

        echo form_label('Last Name: ', 'last');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'input',
            'name' => 'last',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Last Name',
            'value' => $single_student['student_lname']
            );
        echo form_input($data);

        echo form_label('Male ', 'gender');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'radio',
            'name' => 'gender',
            'checked' => 'checked',
            'value' => $single_student['student_gender']
            );
        echo form_radio($data);

        echo form_label('Female ', 'gender');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'radio',
            'name' => 'gender',
            'value' => $single_student['student_gender']
            );
        echo form_radio($data);

        echo "<br />";

        echo form_label('Course', 'course');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'input',
            'name' => 'course',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Student Course',
            'value' => $single_student['student_course']
            );
        echo form_input($data);

        echo form_label('Company', 'company');
        $data = array(
            'id' => 'input',
            'name' => 'company',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Company Name',
            'value' => $single_student['student_company']
            );
        echo form_input($data);

        $data = array(
            'id' => 'update',
            'name' => 'update',
            'value' => 'Update'
            );
        echo form_submit($data);


    echo form_close(); ?>
```

**My View** ( list of data )

```
<?php foreach ($results as $row) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_fname . " " . $row-     >student_lname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_course; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_company; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()."student_list/student_delete/".$row->student_id; ?>">delete</a>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "student_update/show_student/" . $row->student_id; ?>">update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

And this error occurs

**error message**

```
  A PHP Error was encountered
  Severity: Warning
  Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
  Filename: views/view_student_list.php
  Line Number: 27
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you giving the value for `$results` ?

Comment: update query doesn't return any result set

Comment: I am trying to display the updated value into the list of data

Comment: It looks like you expect `$results` to be something you can loop over with `foreach` (like an array). It's worth checking what's *really* there -- one way to do that is putting `var_dump($results);`  just before your loop, and see if it's what you expected.

Comment: What did you get with `var_dump($results)`

Comment: this is the result after I used var_dump: array(0) { }

Comment: I already edited the controller and the model above.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if any value is present in your variable `$results` This error comes only when there is no value in the variable with foreach loop.
To avoid these situations always use :

```
<?php if($results && !empty($results)){ foreach ($results as $row) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_fname . " " . $row-     >student_lname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_course; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->student_company; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()."student_list/student_delete/".$row->student_id; ?>">delete</a>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "student_update/show_student/" . $row->student_id; ?>">update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php } } ?>
```

Also your result variable will not contain any data to loop since your method update_students does not returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are not getting any results back from your update method is because you are not returning anything.

Secondly, I would change your `get_student_id()` method as it doesn't quite fit with MVC principals. It works for this particular task, however, you should really be getting the uri value in the controller and then passing it through to your model:

**Controller method**:

```
public function show_student($id)
{
    $data['single_student'] = $this->student_view_model->get_student_id($id);

    $this->load->view('view_student_update', $data);
}
```

Assuming that "show_student" would be the 2nd uri segment you can do the above.

**Model method**:

```
public function get_student_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_student', array('student_id' => $id));

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

This way you can get the row for the student without depending on the `student_id` always being the 3rd uri segment.

So, with you're results method, you could:

**Controller Meothod**

```
public function update_student()
{

    $data = array(
    'student_fname' => $this->input->post('first'),
    'student_lname' => $this->input->post('last'),
    'student_gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'student_course' => $this->input->post('course'),
    'student_company' => $this->input->post('company')
    );

    $data['results'] = $this->student_view_model->update_student($this->input->post('hid'), $data);

    $this->load->view('view_student_list', $data);
}
```

**Model Method:**

```
public function update_student($id, $data)
{

    $this->db->where('student_id', $id);

    $this->db->update('tbl_student', $data);

    return $this->get_student_id($id);
}
```

Again, with models you should always pass data to them (for quite a few reasons)!

Lastly, I would also think about change the name of `get_student_id()` to something like `get_student_by_id` or `get_student` as `get_student_id()` suggests t me that you are just going to be getting the id. Also, you really should look at using the [Form Validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) in codeigniter as your code is very, **Very** vulnerable at the minute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your code and this errors occurs: Missing argument 1 for Student_update::student_update_info()

Comment: My bad. Just remove the `$id` and `$data` arguments from the update controller method. I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: no data displayed on the table when I removed the arguments $id and $data.

Comment: And you definitely removed it from the method in the controller and not in the model? Also, have you checked that the data is getting posted correctly with the correct names and values? Have you checked if the row is getting updated in the database or not? Are there any errors in your error_log?

Comment: How do I check the errors in my error_log?I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes. I have removed it from the method in the controller. It is also not updated in the database.

Comment: Are you using something like MAMP or XAMPP? Also, is your form definitely posting to the right place? Have you tried adding something like `$post = $this->input->post(); var_dump($post); die();` in you controller update method to see if everything is getting posted correctly?

Comment: this array occurs after trying var_dump($post): array(9) { ["id"]=> string(5) "input" ["name"]=> string(3) "hid" ["value"]=> string(2) "18" ["first"]=> string(13) "Zianne KriKri" ["last"]=> string(8) "Ocubillo" ["gender"]=> string(6) "female" ["course"]=> string(3) "BSN" ["company"]=> string(18) "St. Felix Hospital" ["update"]=> string(6) "Update" }

Comment: in that array I can see that it is updated since I edited the first name but it is not updated in the database when I checked it.

Comment: When I tried using var_dump($data['result']), this one occurs: array(0) { }